# php $_REQUEST doesn't contain cookies

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have some simple code like this:

```
<?php
setcookie("user","test", time() + 3600);
echo $_REQUEST['user']."<br>";
echo $_COOKIE['user'];
?>
```

and this is the result:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in D:\interpub\wwwroot\live\cookie.php on line 3 
test
```

I'm running it on IIS 7.5. I've reloaded the page and I'm sure the browser sends the cookie to the php file (because I have it in $_COOKIE). So why doesn't `$_REQUEST` contain that cookie?

Comment: Apparently, `_COOKIE` doesn't contain the cookies either.

Comment: The $_COOKIE data is just the data that was present when the page was requested.
If you reload, you should have the correct info.

Comment: Are you sure? I have not seen any change log indicating this change

Comment: @user730033, do you have cookies enabled in your web browser? Try to use Firebug or a tool like that to make sure if cookies are really passed within the HTTP request.

Comment: I've used using chrome inspector: It has it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/_REQUEST) on newer PHP setups contains only `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

With the typical PHP 5.3 php.ini `$_COOKIE` is excluded from there by `request_order=GP`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order
And http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Answer (score 10):

COOKIEs are not sent until the next headers are sent .. you won't be able to see them until a page reload.